# Merge / Combine two or more different StyleSheet components in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, merge, styles, react-native

I'm separating  my styles in the following way:

```
styles /
|-- base.js
|-- base.ios.js
|-- base.android.js
```

Each of them exports a StyleSheet component created as in this example:

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default StyleSheet.create({
    statusBar: {
    height: 20
});
```

How can I merge them so I only have one base style object? I'm looking for something like:

```
const baseStyles = mergeStyles(baseStyle, platformStyle);
```

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a built in way to do this, but its trivial to compose objects together. maybe just keep your stylesheet files as plain objects, merge them however, and only call `Stylesheet.create` where you actually insert the style

Comment: @azium yep I thought doing that ... however I wonder if there's an option to merge two already created stylesheet components

Comment: if you want to merge specific styles, just use array: `[base.button, platform.button]`

Comment: thats an option, yep

Answer (score 41):

you are very close:

```
const baseStyles = [baseStyle, platformStyle];
```

basically any component can cascade styles like this:

```
<View style={[styles.style1,styles.style2]}></View>
```

Comment: Yep but only if they support the style, for example if I set a textAlign in a View element, it wont be cascade.

Comment: you saved my day. The merge by {...} doesn't allow for styles in a same component. The correct approach is that you showed.

Comment: This usage has a performance issue. See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57039103/586522

Answer (score 11):

You can also use `StyleSheet.flatten` method. See documentation [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/stylesheet#flatten).

```
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  listItem: {
    flex: 1,
    fontSize: 16,
    color: 'white',
  },
  selectedListItem: {
    color: 'green',
  },
});

StyleSheet.flatten([styles.listItem, styles.selectedListItem]);
// returns { flex: 1, fontSize: 16, color: 'green' }
```

**UPDATE:**

`StyleSheet.flatten` internally uses StyleSheetRegistry.getStyleByID(style) to resolve style objects represented by IDs. IDs enable optimizations through the bridge and memory in general. Referring to style objects directly will deprive you of these optimizations.

So flatten method is better than `style={ [ styles.listItem, styles.selectedListItem ] }`

Comment: Is this method better than using array directly in style props like this?

style={ [ styles.listItem, styles.selectedListItem ] }

Comment: There is a warning about `flatten` [on the docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/stylesheet#flatten): _Exercise caution as abusing this can tax you in terms of optimizations. IDs enable optimizations through the bridge and memory in general. Referring to style objects directly will deprive you of these optimizations._

Answer (score 7):

You can combine style sheets using the spread operator '...', be warned that any variables of the same name will be overwritten by the last instance.

Heres a small demo app to demonstrate:

```js
'use strict';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
   Alert,
   Button,
   StyleSheet,
   Text,
   AppRegistry,
   View,
 } from 'react-native';

class listTest extends Component {

render() {
  return (

   <View style={styles3.myViewBox}>
      <Text style = {styles3.myTextBox1}>
        TEST
      </Text>
    </View>
   );
  }
 }

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  myTextBox1: {
     backgroundColor:'red',
  },
  myViewBox: {
    backgroundColor:'blue',
    margin:15,
    padding:15,
  }

});

const styles2 = StyleSheet.create({
  myTextBox2: {
    backgroundColor:'yellow',
  },
  myViewBox: {
    backgroundColor:'green',
    margin:15,
    padding:15,
  },
});

const styles3 = {...styles,...styles2};

AppRegistry.registerComponent('listTest', () => listTest);
```

EDIT:

If you're running ES5 you can just use:

> const styles3 = Object.assign(styles,styles2);

Comment: > "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

Comment: It is worth noting that this syntax is new in 2018: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: @Green minimum ES6 syntax

Answer (score 1):

Now ReactNative lets you combine two styles using a more functional approach. Use the function StyleSheet.compose so you can do the following as per documentation:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

const App = () => (
  <View style={container}>
    <Text style={text}>React Native</Text>
  </View>
);

const page = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 24,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 30,
    color: '#000'
  },
});

const lists = StyleSheet.create({
  listContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#61dafb',
  },
  listItem: {
    fontStyle: 'italic',
    fontWeight: 'bold'
  },
});

const container = StyleSheet.compose(page.container, lists.listContainer); // if you wanna compose more than one style just use a map.reduce function and compose two at the time until you have consumed you list of styles
const text = StyleSheet.compose(page.text, lists.listItem);

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be to use `StyleSheet.flatten`.

For example

```
<button style={StyleSheet.flatten(styles.btn, {backgroundColor: 'red'})} >Start</button>
```

The above code would create a button that has the properties of `styles.btn`, as well with the color red. You can also use it to combine multiple styles in a StyleSheet object like:

```
StyleSheet.flatten([styles.listItem, styles.selectedListItem])
```